# Are there powershell commands for administering multiple IIS servers from one machine?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, remote-access

I have multiple IIS servers running on different machines. These are all connected via remote web management service to a single machine where I do most of the management.

I want to automate some tasks via powershell. One task I can't find out how to do via powershell is add new connections to the machine where I am doing the remote management from.

Is there a powershell equivalent to this process here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-iis-web-sites/ ?

Comment: What about PowerShell remoting?

Answer (score 1):

The linked article has several steps. Let's see what Powershell can do for each of them.

> The first step is to add the Management Service Role.

Per [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/install-or-uninstall-roles-role-services-or-features#install-roles-role-services-and-features-by-using-windows-powershell-cmdlets):

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name <feature_name> -computerName <computer_name> -Restart
```

Using `get-windowsfeature -computername`, I find that the name of the IIS Management Service role is `Web-Mgmt-Service`, we'll use this:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Mgmt-Service -computerName <computer_name> -Restart
```

> Once installed, you need to start the Web Management Service.

This should do the trick:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName <computername> -Name WMSvc | Start-Service -Verbose
```

> Change it to Automatic if you plan on using this feature often.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName <computername> -Name WMSvc | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
```

> Next, set the EnableRemoteManagement attribute in the Registry to 1

From [this Microsoft scripting blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-edit-the-registry-on-remote-computers/):

Use a combination of `Get-Credential`, `Enter-PSSession`, `Push-Location`, `Set-Location`, `Set-ItemProperty`, and `Pop-Location`.

[This MCPMag.com article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/10/21/enabling-iis-remote-management.aspx) does the same thing, with slightly different commands.

> Next, login to the server where you want to remote manage your IIS servers from. Open the IIS management console and click File -> Connect to a Server

I haven't found a Powershell way to do this part yet. It appears that saved connections are stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\WebManagement\7.0.0.0\InetMgr.preferences`, although the format isn't obvious. But the above commands will allow you to automate most of what you are asking for.